# Describing the Verticies of a Circular Object with Variable Radius

Tags: opengl

Hopefully Clarifying: I'm looking to run a **for loop across all verticies of a triangle fan** that can take 2d vectors for position and direction, along with an arbitrary angle and radius (in the picture below it's 180 degrees) and **produce a similar result to the picture below**

Original Post:Given the position, direction, radius and angle of a light source, I'm trying to describe the verticies of a triangle fan for the light source.  A circle is easy.  I'm trying to replicate something like in this picture, where the direction would be in the positive x direction, and the angle would be pi radians.  The difficulty that I have is that the radius falls off for angles not included, in the picture this corresponds to all verticies to the left of the vertically-oriented verticies.

[image: The General Shape of the Object, With the Angle = 180 Degrees]

Picture taken from the game Full Bore http://www.wholehog-games.com/fullbore/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by interpolating the radius using the dot product with the direction:

```
double dotCutoff = cos(angle / 2);
double exponent = 1;
for(int i = 0; i <= steps; ++i)
{
    double vertexAngle = i * 2 * Pi / steps;
    vec2 vertexDirection = vec2(sin(vertexAngle), cos(vertexAngle));
    double dotDirection = dot(vertexDirection, direction);
    double r = 1;
    if(dotDirection < dotCutoff)
        r = falloff + (1 - falloff) * pow((dotDirection - cutoff)/(cutoff + 1) + 1,exponent);
    emit vertex pos + r * radius * vertexDirection;
}
```

`falloff` is a fraction which specifies the lowest radius. I.e. a `falloff` of `0.2` means that the radius in the opposite direction is 0.2 times the original radius. The `exponent` specifies the descent's steepness.

For a `falloff = 0.5`, `angle = 120°` and `exponent = 1`, you get the following image:

[image: Plot]

You can tune this with the exponent:

`falloff = 0.5, angle = 120°, exponent = 4`:

[image: Plot]

For very small `falloffs` or large angles, you should be aware of this behavior:

`falloff = 0.3, angle = 180°, exponent = 1`:

[image: Plot]

You can adjust the exponent to smoothen the left edge:

`falloff = 0.3, angle = 180°, exponent = 2`:

[image: Plot]